# How to remove string and replace with content found in text file using batch script or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parsing, strings

How to remove string and replace with content found in text file using batch script.

test.txt

```
Version: 4.5.0
Import:
   //MPackages/Project/config/abc.txt                       #head
   //Packages/Project/config/cde.txt                        #head
View: 24234
  //MPackages/Project/config/ac.txt                     #head
```

Remove any text found between "Import:" and "View:" and replace it with content from sample text file..

sample.txt

```
1
2
3
```

Desired output

```
Version: 4.5.0
Import:
   1
   2
   3
View: 24234
   //MPackages/Project/config/ac.txt                     #head
```

sample script

```
[string]$f=gc Test.txt;
$pL=$f.IndexOf('Import:')+'Import:'.Length;$pR=$f.IndexOf('View:');
$s=$f.Remove($pL,$pR-$pL) | set-content Test.txt
```

i removes everything between Import: and View: but it ruins text structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotta parse it.  Go through each line looking for `Import:`. When you find it set a flag, return the sample content, then ignore everything until you get to `View:`. Then start returning everything again. Rinse, repeat.

```
$sampleContent = Get-Content 'Sample.txt'
$inImport = $false

Get-Content -Path 'Test.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if( $inImport )
        {
            if( $_ -like 'View:*' )
            {
                $inImport = $false
                return $_
            }
            return
        }

        if( $_ -like 'Import:*' )
        {
            $inImport = $true
            $_
            return $sampleContent
        }

        return $_

    }
```